# How to keep Lxterminal open after running .desktop shortcut

Tags: command-line, 16.04, lubuntu, lxterminal

I made a .desktop file to compile and execute a c++ file but the terminal (lxterminal - lubuntu) is not holding after running the file.

Although I did mark "Keep terminal window open after command execution." on the .desktop file properties !

I am using Lubuntu 16.04.1 LXDE desktop environment.

Comment: What do you want to do with the terminal after the command execution? Only look at the result, or do you want to run new commands in it?

Comment: I have to look at the result.

Comment: @EbramShehata did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: @VincentWasteels both answers forgot that `-e` doesn't run another shell, so it can't parse command sequence. Just add the shell explicitly and it will work. `Exec=lxterminal -e "/bin/bash -c '/path/to/yourCommand; read -n 1 -s'"`

Answer (score 1):

You can run your command(s) via a shellscript. (Maybe you do that already.) And at the end of the shellscript you add a line, for example like this:

```
read -p "Press Enter to close this window"
```

Then you can scroll the window and check the output from your command(s), and then press Enter to get rid of the terminal window.

---

I don't know why the first method did not work. Maybe your script or some program called by it is sending a signal that finishes the script at once (without reaching the final statement). You could try to fix that, but maybe it is easier to run in an **xterm** window (tweaked to look better and with the `-hold` option.

Please compare how these two command lines work:

```
xterm -e cat ~/.bashrc
xterm -hold -e cat ~/.bashrc
```

You can tweak the xterm window to look better, for example like this

```
xterm -title "Click x in the top right corner to close me" -fa default -fs 10 -bg '#2b2c2b' -fg '#f0f0f0' -sb -rightbar -hold -e cat ~/.bashrc
```

Put the name of your script after -e in the xterm command line, or start the xterm in interactive mode (with the hold feature), and start your script in xterm.

Comment: It didn't work , the terminal closes .

Comment: @EbramShehata I got crazy for 1 hour. Seems that `-e, --command` doesn't work seamessly. Change your `lxterminal -e "your command"` for `lxterminal --command="your command"`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is optimal for you use case, but you can put `yourCommand; read -n 1 -s` in the *Exec* line of your *.desktop* file, causing the terminal to wait for one character input *(silently, not echoing it back to stdout)*.

You should end with something like this:

`Exec=lxterminal -e "/path/to/yourCommand; read -n 1 -s"`

Also can use `&&` or `||` according to you app exit value/code, *waiting only if execution was successful, for example:*

`Exec=lxterminal -e "/path/to/yourCommand && read -n 1 -s"`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Non of these two methods worked :(  , the terminal closes .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
lxterminal -e bash -c 'top; bash'
```

Just replace "top" with your command.